# How do I implement camera changing from front to back camera

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Below is the code for the camera section, I tried adding in a boolean to detect when the front camera is activated but I receive an error.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation 
class MainCameraCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var photoOutPut: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var image: UIImage?
    var usingFrontCamera = false   
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    func setupCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    }
    func setupDevice(usingFrontCamera:Bool = false){
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices   
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }
        if usingFrontCamera {
            currentCamera = frontCamera
        } else {
            currentCamera = backCamera
        }
    }
    func setupInput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutPut = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            photoOutPut?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:[AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            captureSession.addOutput(photoOutPut!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    func setupPreviewLayer(){
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    @IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutPut?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self as! AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
    }
    //Flip to front and back camera
    @IBAction func FlipThe_camera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Flip touched")
        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
        usingFrontCamera = !usingFrontCamera
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice(usingFrontCamera:usingFrontCamera)
        setupInput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
}
```

> collectionViewAttemptOfPagingAttempt002[2908:834004] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[AVCaptureSession addOutput:] Cannot add output
>    to capture session
>   
>      ->
>       ->  because more than one output of the same type is
>   unsupported'

Comment: **Setup the capture session. In general it is not safe to mutate an AVCaptureSession or any of its inputs, outputs, or connections from multiple threads at the same time. Why not do all of this on the main queue? Because -[AVCaptureSession startRunning] is a blocking call which can take a long time. We dispatch session setup to the sessionQueue so that the main queue isn't blocked, which keeps the UI responsive.**

Comment: You need also to call `self.captureSession.beginConfiguration()` before trying to `removeInput` and once you finish it you need to call `self.captureSession.commitConfiguration()` .

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for your advise what functions would need to go on the snub thread in particular

Comment: I have posted how you can setup your capture device asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not checking if you can add input and/or output before adding them to your capture session. Btw you don't need to setup the preview layer again when switching your camera and you need only one captureDevice:

```
if captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
}
```

and

```
if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutPut) {
    captureSession.addOutput(photoOutPut)
}
```

Your CollectionViewCell code should look something like this:

```
class MainCameraCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    private var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private var sessionQueue: DispatchQueue!
    private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
    private  var photoOutPut: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    private var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var image: UIImage?
    var usingFrontCamera = false
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInput()
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
    func setupCaptureSession(){
        captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
        sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
    }
    func setupDevice(usingFrontCamera: Bool = false){
        sessionQueue.async {
            let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified)
            let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
            for device in devices {
                if usingFrontCamera && device.position == .front {
                    self.captureDevice = device
                } else if device.position == .back {
                    self.captureDevice = device
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func setupInput() {
        sessionQueue.async {
            do {
                let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.captureDevice)
                if self.captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
                    self.captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
                }
                self.photoOutPut = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
                self.photoOutPut.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:[AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
                if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutPut) {
                    self.captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutPut)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer, at: 0)
    }
    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
    @IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoOutPut.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }
    //Flip to front and back camera
    @IBAction func FlipThe_camera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
        usingFrontCamera = !usingFrontCamera
        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice(usingFrontCamera: usingFrontCamera)
        setupInput()
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }
}
```

[Sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zujz8krt9blit3r/TableViewCamera.zip?dl=1)