# Switching from the front camera to the back camera causes my the app to crash?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, segue

The  app crashes with an error

> No active and enabled video connection'

After taking a picture with the back camera segueing to another screen dismissing the screen and returning back to the camera screen flipping from the back camera to the front camera and taking another picture the app crashes below is the code for the camera screen.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol gestureDelegate{
func gestureDelegate()
}

protocol previewSegueDelegate {
func previewSegueDelegate(image:UIImage,device:AVCaptureDevice)
}

class MainCameraCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var gdelegate: gestureDelegate?
var pdelegate: previewSegueDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
private var sessionQueue: DispatchQueue!
var captureConnection = AVCaptureConnection()

var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

var photoOutPut: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var image: UIImage?

 var usingFrontCamera = false

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupCaptureSession()
    setupDevice()
    setupInput()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    startRunningCaptureSession()
    print("Inside of camera cell")
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MainCameraCollectionViewCell.tapEdit(sender:)))
    addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
}

@objc func tapEdit(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
    gdelegate?.gestureDelegate()
    guard let device = currentCamera else { return }

    if sender.state == .changed {

        let maxZoomFactor = device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor
        let pinchVelocityDividerFactor: CGFloat = 5.0

        do {

            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }

            let desiredZoomFactor = device.videoZoomFactor + atan2(sender.velocity, pinchVelocityDividerFactor)
            device.videoZoomFactor = max(1.0, min(desiredZoomFactor, maxZoomFactor))

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
func setupCaptureSession(){
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
    sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "session queue")
}

func setupDevice(usingFrontCamera:Bool = false){
    sessionQueue.async {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
    let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

    for device in devices{
        if usingFrontCamera && device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
            self.currentCamera = device
        } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
            self.currentCamera = device
        }
    }
    }
}

func setupInput() {
    sessionQueue.async {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.currentCamera!)
            if self.captureSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
                self.captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            }
            self.photoOutPut = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            self.photoOutPut?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format:[AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
            if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutPut!) {
                self.captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutPut!)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    }
func setupPreviewLayer(){
    cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
}

func startRunningCaptureSession(){
    captureSession.startRunning()
}


@IBAction func cameraButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoOutPut?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self as! AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
}


@IBAction func FlipThe_camera(_ sender: UIButton) {
print("Flip Touched")
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
        for input in inputs {
            captureSession.removeInput(input)
        }
    }
    usingFrontCamera = !usingFrontCamera
    setupCaptureSession()
    setupDevice(usingFrontCamera: usingFrontCamera)
    setupInput()
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
    startRunningCaptureSession()
}

}


 extension MainCameraCollectionViewCell: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate{
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, 
didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation(){
        print(imageData)
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)
     //   performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPhoto_segue", sender: nil)
        if(self.image == nil){
            print("The image is empty")
        }
        pdelegate?.previewSegueDelegate(image: self.image!, device: currentCamera!)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Try [searching on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bios%5d%20No%20active%20and%20enabled%20video%20connection).

Comment: @rmaddy none of the other answers were able to help me resolve my problem could you direct me to one that might be able to

Comment: Why do you have two SO accounts? possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727766/how-do-i-implement-camera-changing-from-front-to-back-camera/48739376#48739376

Comment: Why do you still using 3 captureDevices ? Btw You are already using part of the code I posted at your question but you haven't given any feedback there. Do you know how to mark an answer as correct or at least upvote an answer if you think it is helpful ?